# Offline OSM files to run for OSMAnd Using OsmAndMapCreator

Tags: openstreetmap, osmand, osmandmapcreator, osm.pbf

I am trying to create offline OSM files to run for OSMAnd using these [instructions](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/CreateOfflineMapsForYourself):

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties -Xms256M -Xmx2560M -cp "./OsmAndMapCreator.jar:./lib/OsmAnd-core.jar:./lib/*.jar" net.osmand.data.index.IndexBatchCreator ./batch.xml
```

I am getting net.osmand.data.index.IndexBatchCreator class cannot be found error.

I have updated batch.xml to point to my folders as:

```
<process directory_for_osm_files="/opt/OpenStreetMap/osm_files"
directory_for_index_files="/opt/OpenStreetMap/index_files"
directory_for_generation="/opt/OpenStreetMap/gen_files"
```

specifies my working folders and those folders exists.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "cd" into the OsmandMapCreator main directory before executing the command. The java classpath is relative to the main directory.